# Git ask me to commit hundreds of files whereas I have changed only 2 of them

Tags: git, bitbucket

This morning I wanted to commit my changes (only 2 files), but git tells me  I need to commit hundreds of files.

When I want to see the diff of some files , it (git plugin intellij) tells me that content are identicals.

Yesterday I had no such problem.
I don't understand. How can I tell git that all these files have not changed?

Comment: Could be, depending on your IDE settings you might changed the file format or file permissions

Comment: End-of-lines might have changed? Do you have any developers on Windows?

Comment: yes, some are using windows. is there a way to avoid that on my computer (ubuntu) ? but they have not worked on all these files though.

Comment: End of lines has surely been changed. You should invest in using `.gitattributes`. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings